# How to calculate scrolling speed of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to calculate the speed (in pixel/millis) for a recyclerView. Currently I am overriding `onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)` and dividing the `dx` or `dy` by the time difference between current call to the method and last call to the method.

The speed that I get is generally correct, but there are peaks locally. Sudden increase and decrease in speed. Although to a human eye speed seems pretty smooth.

Should I follow some different approach? Any suggestions are welcome.

Image of the speed graph. This is when I fling the recyclerView.
[image]

Comment: By "peaks locally" do are you referring to the initial peak in the chart? If not what peaks?

Comment: The initial peak is expected as I flinged the view there. But, once it starts decelerating, I should be smooth. By locally I mean the ones like those around 30.

Comment: @n.arrow001 Are you using milliseconds? I've tried an approach similar to this but since `onScrolled` is called too often, the time difference is in the majority of cases 0.

Comment: @n.arrow001 Are you using milliseconds? I've tried an approach similar to this but since `onScrolled` is called too often, the time difference is in the majority of cases 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the method you have used is your best option. The localised peaks will be a result of variation in painting/assigning recyclerview list items. Both your Android phone and Android application are running a myriad of processes at once. This will result in minor increases and decreases in your chart line at seemingly arbitrary points.

As you noted the human eye cannot see these differences though, so I would not concern yourself with them, your data will be correct.